# A-frame box is a link

Tags: html, aframe, virtual-reality, box

I was wondering how it would be possible in A-frame (aframe.io) turn a box into a link. I have the link structure and the box structure but I want the box to turn into a link. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a-frame`s [link](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/link.html#sidebar) component uses [window.location](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/link.js#L166) to change websites, you can do the same within a custom component:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // component declaration
  AFRAME.registerComponent("mylink", {
    // define a url in the schema
    schema: {
      href: {}
    },
    init: function() {
      // when clicked - change the location:
      this.el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        window.location = this.data.href;
      })
    }
  })
</script>

<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
  <a-box position="0 1 -2" color="blue" mylink="href: https://aframe.io/;"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

---

You could also grab the anchor (a) element and do `anchorElement.click();` instead of changing the `window.location` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a website that makes Icosahedrons links to the other sections of the site
(Ignore the absurd amount of components, I'm copying and pasting from the site code)

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.3/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-text-geometry-component@0.5.1/dist/aframe-text-geometry-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@^4.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-debug-cursor-component/dist/aframe-debug-cursor-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/v4.0.1/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>

<a-scene>
<a-entity
          link="href: personal.html; title: Personal Projects"
          geometry="primitive: icosahedron; depth: 0.5; height: 0.5; width: 0.5; skipCache: false; segmentsHeight: 1; segmentsWidth: 1; segmentsDepth: 1"
          material="color: #ff6600"
          animation__mouseenter="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; to: blue; startEvents: mouseenter; dur: 500"
          animation__mouseleave="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; to: #ff6600; startEvents: mouseleave; dur: 500"
        ></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

This is A-Frame 1.0.3 so I'm not sure if it works in the new version.